# blueimp jquery-file-upload how to cancel 1 file before upload

Tags: javascript, jquery, file-upload, blueimp

I am using the following library
https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki

I am showing the selected files after (add files) button is selected.  I am not showing the demo grid showing cancel button or upload

I have a button which does the submit (see below).
I would like to cancel the upload of one of the files selected before this upload button is selected.

Walking through the code i see that when i finally hit submit, it calls fileuploadsubmit for each file uploaded.

I would like to show to the user grid of files selected, then allow them to cancel one of them by picking a link to remove from data.  All the samples i am finding online tend to parent().remove() thereby removing from visual grid.

How can i do without showing that grid?

ie..

```
                ...
                add: function (e, data) {

                $.each(data.files, function (index, file) {
                    files += file.name;
                });
                $('#files').text(files);

                viewModel.Add(data);

                data.context = $('#btnUpload')
                    .click(function () {
                        data.submit();
                        return false;
                    });
            },
            ......


            $('#fileupload').bind('fileuploadsubmit', function (e, data) {
            // The example input, doesn't have to be part of the upload form:
            //var input = $('#input');
            //data.formData = {example: input.val()};

            var countryId = 1; //viewModel.selectedCountry().CountryId()
            var selected = 'test'; //$('#lstTemplate option:selected').text();

            data.formData = { templateType: selected, countryId: countryId };
            if (data.formData.templateType == 'Select') {
                data.context.find('button').prop('disabled', false);
                return false;
            }
        });
```

Comment: if all submits are bind on one button, there is no way to remove only one of them

Comment: when i click add, does the plugin add the files to upload to some array/collection? (if yes, then it would be possible to remove?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually is possible to remove one file from data.files. 
I'm using KnockoutJs web-component in which I'm storing instance of "upload object" and I have observable array for file list ...

My configuration is:

```
.fileupload({
            url: DataServiceBaseUrl + '/api/Ruleset/BatchImport',
            dataType: 'json',
            singleFileUploads: false,
            replaceFileInput: false,
            add: function (e, data) {
...
```

what I did is

```
this.RemoveFile = function(index){
   this.UploadInstance.files.splice(index,1);
   this.UploadFiles.splice(index,1);
}
```

and template was:

```
 <!-- ko foreach: UploadFiles -->
    <div><span data-bind="text: name"></span><button data-bind="click: function() { $component.RemoveFile($index()); }">delete</button></div>
 <!-- /ko -->
```