# blueimpfile jquery file upload remove on fileuploaddone with angular

Tags: angularjs, jquery-file-upload

I have read quite a lot of post here on this but can't find a solution which work for my implementation:

I wan to remove the uploaded file from the queue on success. blueimp jquery file upload propose a call back "fileuploaddone"

```
  $scope.$on('fileuploaddone', function(event, file){
    ... /*remove file from queue and UI*/
    });
  });
```

There doesn't seam to have any handle like an index number to help with this.

I use  (slim-lang)

```
li data-ng-repeat="file in queue"
   ...
```

as the main UI loop over the queue with angular

What is the best way to remove the file from the queue?

thank you!

[Blueimp jQuery File Upload - hide file from queue after upload done responce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24727116/blueimp-jquery-file-upload-hide-file-from-queue-after-upload-done-responce)

[blueimp jquery-file-upload how to cancel 1 file before upload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22052146/blueimp-jquery-file-upload-how-to-cancel-1-file-before-upload)

Comment: Did you figure anything out on this?

Comment: no just switch to angular-file-upload